# How to draw a line in Minecraft with Fabric

Tags: java, render, minecraft, lwjgl, minecraft-fabric

### Final target: draw a line in sky

#### Env

Config in `build.properties`

```
    minecraft_version=1.18.2
    yarn_mappings=1.18.2+build.3
    loader_version=0.13.3
    fabric_version=0.51.1+1.18.2
```

Development environment:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- IDEA 2021.3.2(CE)
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.1+12 (build 17.0.1+12)

#### Code

SkyRenderer code

```java
@Environment(EnvType.CLIENT)
public class OverworldSkyRenderer implements DimensionRenderingRegistry.SkyRenderer {
    @Override
    public void render(WorldRenderContext context) {
        RenderSystem.disableTexture();
        RenderSystem.enableDepthTest();
        RenderSystem.depthFunc(515);
        RenderSystem.enableBlend();
        RenderSystem.defaultBlendFunc();
        RenderSystem.depthMask(false);

        Tessellator tessellator = Tessellator.getInstance();
        BufferBuilder bufferBuilder = tessellator.getBuffer();

        RenderSystem.setShader(GameRenderer::getPositionColorShader);
        bufferBuilder.begin(VertexFormat.DrawMode.LINES, VertexFormats.POSITION_COLOR);
        bufferBuilder.vertex(0f,0f,0f).color(255,255,255,255).next();
        bufferBuilder.vertex(3f,3f,3f).color(255,255,255,255).next();
        tessellator.draw();

        RenderSystem.enableCull();
        RenderSystem.depthMask(true);
        RenderSystem.disableBlend();
        RenderSystem.defaultBlendFunc();
        RenderSystem.enableTexture();
    }
}
```

And Mod initialization code

```java
public class MainMod implements ModInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onInitialize() {
        // Register sky renderer
        DimensionRenderingRegistry.registerSkyRenderer(
                RegistryKey.of(Registry.WORLD_KEY, new Identifier("overworld")),
                new OverworldSkyRenderer()
        );
        DimensionRenderingRegistry.registerDimensionEffects(
                new Identifier("overworld"),
                new DimensionEffects.End()
        );
    }
}
```

#### Result and Assumption

But it did not work, at least I did not find any line in my view(`F5` has been used).

I consulted some [code](https://github.com/gnembon/fabric-carpet/blob/d27767ba981a2f7eb0ca9287df1773e230bae1f5/src/main/java/carpet/script/utils/ShapesRenderer.java#L453) of [fabric-carpet](https://github.com/gnembon/fabric-carpet)

There are some difference, but I think these are not the key point

- Package import

  In carpet, it includes `com.mojang.blaze3d.vertex`, but I cannot find this package in my IDEA. And when I cloned carpet and built it, `import com.mojang.blaze3d.vertex.*;` was removed, and `endVertex()` was changed to `next()`.
- `begin()` function

  In carpet, it uses `DEBUG_LINES` and I used `LINES`, I think they should have no difference in rendering. And I tried `DEBUG_LINES` later, still no line.

Here are some of my assumptions:

- In carpet, these functions seem to be used as APIs for script, is there any more operations when rendering lines?
- I just said I did not see these lines, maybe they are invisible or behind me? Before this, I rendered some image in sky and that worked, and if vertexes are rendered in wrong order, image can be invisible.
- SkyRenderer cannot render lines? (Least likely >_<)

If anyone can help me?

Comment: Unfortunately, stackoverflow isn't a platform where we give code, we fix it. We cannot fix your code without the desired affect and the current error or output.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, but I really do not know how to describe it, I can only show my code. And I think I have got a idea of this problem, and I am going to show that.

Comment: You can check out the sources of minihud mod, there's a lot of rendering going on:
https://github.com/maruohon/minihud/tree/liteloader_1.12.2/src/main/java/fi/dy/masa/minihud/renderer

Answer (score 1):

**My solution is using `VertexFormat.Mode.DEBUG_LINES`**

Here I found an [issue](https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MinecraftForge/issues/8083) related to this question, although it is Forge, not Fabric.

In this issue, it found that `LINES`, `LINE_STRIP` cannot be rendered for that they do not pass correct mode argument when invoking `glDrawElements`, so it cannot be rendered correctly. And `DEBUG_LINES` and `DEBUG_LINE_STRIP` have correct mode.

Before I found this issue, I tried some code in `ChunkBoarderDebugRenderer`, which uses `VertexFormat.Mode.DEBUG_LINE_STRIP`, and it did work!

So what I did was changing:

```java
bufferBuilder.begin(VertexFormat.DrawMode.LINES, VertexFormats.POSITION_COLOR);
```

to

```java
bufferBuilder.begin(VertexFormat.DrawMode.DEBUG_LINES, VertexFormats.POSITION_COLOR);
```

And the vertex of second point(Camera looks at Z-negative, which means you can only see the point with negative z. I am noob for opengl T_T)

So here is my changed code

```java
@Environment(EnvType.CLIENT)
public class OverworldSkyRenderer implements DimensionRenderingRegistry.SkyRenderer {
    @Override
    public void render(WorldRenderContext context) {
        // ...
        RenderSystem.setShader(GameRenderer::getPositionColorShader);
        bufferBuilder.begin(VertexFormat.DrawMode.DEBUG_LINES, VertexFormats.POSITION_COLOR);
        bufferBuilder.vertex(1f,0f,-3f).color(255,0,0,255).next();
        bufferBuilder.vertex(1f,3f,-3f).color(255,0,0,255).next();
        tessellator.draw();
        // ...
    }
}
```

And the screenshot

[image: After changed code]

However, `TRIANGLE` cannot work, although it has correct mode value. I am trying to figure it out.